# Item Wrong Length 1 Instead of 50 Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, data-mining, tukey

I'm dealing with a csv file consists of 2 columns and 51 rows in total.

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep = ',')
data.columns=['x_column', 'y_column']
```

Then I perform linear regresssion

```
X = data.iloc[:, 0].values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = data.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1, 1)
lr = LinearRegression()
```

Next thing I need to perform is Tukey Method.

```
X = data.iloc[[0], :].values
y = data.iloc[[1], :].values
```

Then I plotted the boxes and found out my range is between -40 to 10.

```
data.boxplot(return_type='dict')
plt.plot()
```

I need to assign my outliers to a value in order to remove them before training my dataset again. And this is where I have a problem.

```
y_column = X[:, 1]
data_outliers = (y_column > 0.0)
data[data_outliers]
```

When I run this last part I get **Item wrong length 1 instead of 50.** error and I don't know how to solve that. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data_outliers = (y_column > 0.0).ravel()
```

The problem was that your `data_outliers` was a numpy column with two dimensions (shape: (1,50)) and that was impossible to mask the df like that... ravel just flattened it...

Comment: Theoretically you might be right @adir but it didn't solve the problem and I'm still having the same error.

Comment: Well it seems that the way you initialized y column was wrong, please print more data so we can investigate better...

Comment: Well after I run the code in the third section I printed out the first 5 rows of the both columns and it worked perfectly. I guess I went correct until I past the first three sections @adir